# What does the following LINQ statement equal to in simple sql?

Tags: linq

```
 query_TMEditSheet = _
                    From tm In Context_DomainService1TMTM.GetTMTMSQuery()
                    Where tm.tmsDate = MainPage.TimeSheetDateSelect_selectdate.Date
                    Where tm.tmsUserID = MainPage.user_userID
```

Using where two times like this means, AND/ ANDALSO/OR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using where twice would mean AND. Something like:

```
SELECT tm.* FROM ... tm WHERE tm.tmsDate = ? AND tm.tmsUserID = ?
```

You would probably have the same effect by putting both conditions in the same `Where` statement, like:

```
Where tm.tmsDate = MainPage.TimeSheetDateSelect_selectdate.Date && tm.tmsUserID = MainPage.user_userID
```

but what you have is more readable IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Where` two times in a row like this corresponds to `AND` in SQL. SQL does not have an `ANDALSO` operator.